# Me muestra este echo "ERROR: Consulta".mysqli_connect_error(); de la función consultar() y no se como arreglarlo, tampoco me hace las consultas

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

```
<section id="nov-index">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Novedades <small>Productos</small></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <?php
                  //include 'library/configServer.php';
                  include 'library/consulSQL.php';
                  $consulta= ejecutarSQL::consultar("select * from producto where Stock > 0 limit 6");
                  $totalproductos = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);
                  echo $totalproductos;
                  if($totalproductos>0){
                      while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){
                         echo '
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                             <div class="thumbnail">
                               <img src="assets/img-products/'.$fila['Imagen'].'">
                               <div class="caption">
                                 <h3>'.$fila['Marca'].'</h3>
                                 <p>'.$fila['NombreProd'].'</p>
                                 <p>$'.$fila['Precio'].'</p>
                                 <p class="text-center">
                                     <a href="infoProd.php?CodigoProd='.$fila['CodigoProd'].'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp; Detalles</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                     <button value="'.$fila['CodigoProd'].'" class="btn btn-success btn-sm botonCarrito"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>&nbsp; Añadir</button>
                                 </p>

                               </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>     
                         ';
                     }   
                  }else{
                      echo '<h2>No hay productos registrados en la tienda</h2>';
                  }  
              ?>  
            </div>
         </div>
    </section>
```

y este es el include donde hago las consultas y donde tengo el echo

```
<?php
/* Clase para ejecutar las consultas a la Base de Datos*/
class ejecutarSQL {
    public static function conectar(){
        $enlace= new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","","store"); //establecemos conexion con la bdd

        //en caso de errores de conexión
        $error=$enlace->connect_errno;

        if($error!=null){
            echo "ERROR: No se pudo establecer la conexión con la BDD";
            echo "ERROR: Depuracion".mysqli_connect_error();
            exit;
        }
        echo "CONEXIÓN ESTABLECIDA!";
        return $enlace;  
    }
    public static function consultar($consulta) {
        if (!$sql = mysqli_query($consulta, ejecutarSQL::conectar())) {
            echo "ERROR: Consulta".mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        return $sql;
        echo "correcto";
    }  
}
/* Clase para hacer las consultas Insertar, Eliminar y Actualizar */
class consultasSQL{
    public static function InsertSQL($tabla, $campos, $valores) {
        if (!$sql = ejecutarSQL::consultar("Insert into $tabla ($campos) VALUES($valores)")) {
            die("Ha ocurrido un error al insertar los datos en la tabla $tabla");
        }
        return $sql;
    }
    public static function DeleteSQL($tabla, $condicion) {
        if (!$sql = ejecutarSQL::consultar("Delete from $tabla where $condicion")) {
            die("Ha ocurrido un error al eliminar los registros en la tabla $tabla");
        }
        return $sql;
    }
    public static function UpdateSQL($tabla, $campos, $condicion) {
        if (!$sql = ejecutarSQL::consultar("Update $tabla set $campos where $condicion")) {
            die("Ha ocurrido un error al actualizar los datos en la tabla $tabla");
        }
        return $sql;
    }
}
```

Comment: Creo que llamas _$consulta= ejecutarSQL::consultar("...");_ pero nunca llamas conectar() así que imagino que el error es ése

Comment: Tus consulta son susceptibles a [`Injección SQL`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/16597). Te recomiendo que leas el articulo y utilices consulta preparadas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error se debe a que estas pasando mal los parámetros a la función [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)

> mixed mysqli_query(mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT])

### Solución:

Primero debes pasar el `$link` a la conexión de la DB

#### Ejemplo

```
public static function consultar($consulta) {
    if (!$sql = mysqli_query(self::conectar(), $consulta)) {
        echo "ERROR: Consulta".mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    return $sql;
    echo "correcto";
}
```

Comment: mil gracias! Me funcionó

Comment: pero en que parte se coloca no entiendo